# Hide the Favorites Tray from a specific home screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, home-screen

At the bottom of my main home screen, I have the Favorites Tray with the default icons (Call, Contacts, Messages and Menu).

This Favorites Tray was only visible on my main home screen, but now it appears on all home screens as I swipe between them.

## Question

How can I hide the Favorites Tray from a specific(s) home screen(s) ?

Comment: Doesn't the Ace use TouchWiz?

Comment: What is "other screens"? Can you post a screenshot?